# Display Stats in Table Using R

Tags: r, output

I'm working on some stats like mean, median, correlation etc using **R**.
Is there a way to display the results of the code in table form? 
Here's a sample of my code:

```
cor(Moisture, pH)
cor(Moisture, NH3)
cor(Moisture, NH3DM) 
cor(Moisture, NDM) 
cor(Moisture, N)
cor(Moisture, TKN)
cor(Moisture, X.Ash)
cor(Moisture, CN)
cor(Moisture, EC1.5)
```

At the moment the output on the **R** console is:

```
> cor(Moisture, pH)
[1] -0.03154892
> cor(Moisture, NH3)
[1] -0.2814583
> cor(Moisture, NH3DM) 
[1] -0.1099614
> cor(Moisture, NDM) 
[1] 0.08306996
> cor(Moisture, N)
[1] -0.3728169
> cor(Moisture, TKN)
[1] 0.06975473
> cor(Moisture, X.Ash)
[1] -0.2749583
> cor(Moisture, CN)
[1] 0.002943823
> cor(Moisture, EC1.5)
[1] -0.4049512
```

I feel this is quite messy and for my class we're only meant to use **R**.

Any thoughts?

Comment: add them all into data.frame()(as a single column) with rownames() also set

Comment: you can save a bit of typing by adding all of these in to one `cor` function ie `cor(Moisture, cbind(pH, NH3, NH3DM, ... etc))` . This will return a named vector.

Comment: These 2 solutions worked, but I liked the output of the vector. I think I'm mistaking what R can actually do in terms of output - I thought it could export results rather than just display them on the console. For instance, I get the output but when i copy and paste to excel it's in a single column rather than a column per variable. Is there a way around this? Thanks

Comment: This question is a good one for many people trying to do univariate & bivariate summary stats in R (questions starts with univariate, then switches to bivariate).  It would be much easier if we had code to replicate data for this request or at least more information on what sort of table content @Bake.G would like to display.  I will over an example solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution that gets univariate (e.g. mean, std. dev.) and bivariate (e.g. correlation) data into a single object that can then be send to your favorite markdown options (e.g. kable) and made into nice looking summary tables.

I am using the mtcars data since it is easy to source and has plenty of numeric variables.  My example code uses comments to explain my thinking along the way.  The descr() function is great at providing summary stats, but is a bit annoying to extract the data for usability.  Also note that fashion() turns the correlations into text values, which is fine since at that point they are for the table and not computation.

```
library(dplyr) # for pipes & select()
library(corrr) # for correlation stuff
library(summarytools) # for descr()
library(stringr)  # for str_to_title()

# load testing data
data("mtcars")
# subset data to drop the binary variables (or any others you don't want); could code as keep variables, but I have fewer here to drop
d1 <- mtcars %>% select(-vs, -am)
# sort so columns are in alphabetical order, this will help ensure data quality in the next steps
d1 <- d1[,order(colnames(d1))]

# get & store quant summary stats (summarytools function)
d2 <- descr(d1)
# save names for later
names.stats <- rownames(d2)
names.var <- colnames(d2)
# extract stored summary stats into usable dataframe
d3 <- as.vector(d2[1:7, 1:ncol(d2)])
d3 <- round(as.data.frame(matrix(d3, nrow=7, ncol=ncol(d2), byrow=FALSE)),2)
colnames(d3) <- str_to_title(names.var)

# save correlation matrix as dataframe
c1 <- d3 %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% correlate() %>% shave(upper=TRUE) %>% fashion(leading_zeros=TRUE, decimals = 2, na_print = "—")
colnames(c1) <- paste0("Cor.", colnames(c1))

# transpose & add back summary stat names
d3 <- t(d3)
colnames(d3) <- names.stats[1:7]

# add correlations to rest of the summary stats
d3 <- cbind(d3, c1[,2:10])
```

Not the prettiest output for SO, but this is what you should get by this point.  It's ready to send into your favorite markdown functions for presentation quality table-making.

```
       Mean Std.Dev   Min     Q1 Median     Q3    Max Cor.Carb Cor.Cyl Cor.Disp Cor.Drat Cor.Gear Cor.Hp Cor.Mpg Cor.Qsec Cor.Wt
Carb   2.81    1.62  1.00   2.00   2.00   4.00   8.00        —       —        —        —        —      —       —        —      —
Cyl    6.19    1.79  4.00   4.00   6.00   8.00   8.00     0.74       —        —        —        —      —       —        —      —
Disp 230.72  123.94 71.10 120.65 196.30 334.00 472.00     0.96    0.85        —        —        —      —       —        —      —
Drat   3.60    0.53  2.76   3.08   3.70   3.92   4.93     0.69    0.93     0.73        —        —      —       —        —      —
Gear   3.69    0.74  3.00   3.00   4.00   4.00   5.00     0.67    0.93     0.72     1.00        —      —       —        —      —
Hp   146.69   68.56 52.00  96.00 123.00 180.00 335.00     0.99    0.80     0.98     0.76     0.75      —       —        —      —
Mpg   20.09    6.03 10.40  15.35  19.20  22.80  33.90     0.91    0.92     0.93     0.92     0.91   0.95       —        —      —
Qsec  17.85    1.79 14.50  16.88  17.71  18.90  22.90     0.60    0.87     0.63     0.99     0.98   0.67    0.86        —      —
Wt     3.22    0.98  1.51   2.54   3.33   3.65   5.42     0.89    0.91     0.92     0.91     0.90   0.94    1.00     0.85      —
```

Answer (score 1):

Store all the data you want to display in a data frame df. Then use the stargazer package.

```
install.packages("stargazer")
library(stargazer)
stargazer(df, align = TRUE, type = "text")
```